# Drop reference when only a single link to it

Tags: c#, reference, garbage-collection

I am storing a list of delegates in a dictionary, and then invoking them when required, problem is, when UI is no longer visible, the references to the delegates still exist, and when the UI shows up again, its a new instance, adds new references in addition to the old ones, thus calling twice the amount.

Design issues aside, is there a way of putting a constraint on a reference when storing it, to say that if the dictionary is the only place its stored then discard it and return null?

Comment: Don't you know when the UI is going to become invisible? That would be a good time to remove all the references to it.

Comment: Is there any way to use a [Weak Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the delegate in the dictionary?

Comment: @Klors, I think hooking into the UI close is the only way, a WeakReference cannot guarantee me that it will be removed in the space between closing the UI and reopening.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله you could force the garbage collection before opening the UI again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice would be just `.Clear()` the dictionary when the UI becames invisible

Comment: Clearing the dictionary won't work, I'm more than happy to share code that shows why. Clearing it only removes it from the dictionary, and since .NET is a reference counting language and the UI still holds a reference, the delegates still exist, and now you have zombie objects.

Comment: @RonBeyer that would be true if the OP uses delegates as events. Then you would need to unsubscribe them additionally to the Clear()-call. From the question it's not obvious what kind of delegates they are, maybe that are just single actions that are executed at some time and are never held by the UI at all.

Comment: @RonBeyer  Just to nitpick a little, .NET does not do reference counting. It uses Mark&Sweep.